# How to remove } character from liquid string

Tags: string, character, liquid

In Liquid, one can remove a character `X` from a liquid string like so,

```
{{ 'random_string' | remove:'X' }}
```

E.g. the `{` character can be removed in this way.

However, removing the `}` character this way gives the following error,

```
Liquid syntax error (line 15): Variable '{{ 'random_string' | remove:"}' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\}\}/
```

Which probably has to do with the usage of the `}` character in the Liquid language.

**Question**

How do I remove the `}` character from the string?

Comment: Did you simply try to escape it by adding \ before the }?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be using the *url_encode* filter, then removing the encoded string:

```
{% capture my_variable %}hello}}worl}d{% endcapture %}
{{ my_variable | url_encode | remove: "%7D"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create your own tag.

```
<project>/<app>/templatetags/clean_string.py
```

Insert this code into it.

```
import re

from django import template
register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def clean_string(value):
    regex = '[^-_.,!?@%\w\d]+'
    return re.sub(regex, '', value)
```

After that, register it in the settings...

```
<project>/<projectName>/settings.py

'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
            ],
            'libraries': {
                'clean_string': '<project>.templatetags.clean_string'
            }
        },
```

At the beginning of your .html template Add tag loading

`{% load clean_string %}`

This filter can be applied to any string.

For example:

```
{{ '[tes{t}!'|clean_string }}
```

The filter can be adjusted in a variable ...

```
regex = '[^-_.,!?@%\w\d]+'
```

Output:

> test!